# Where to put SQLite Database So It's Available to Other Apps

Tags: codenameone

I need to do some additional troubleshooting on a SQLite database.  I want to use a db utility to open the file but my device is not able to be rooted.  I wanted to copy the db to a storage location where it would not be blocked by the root security but I can't figure it out.  How can I make a copy of the SQLite database in a location on Android that is accessible to other apps?

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the SQLite database to the SDCard using the `FileSystemStorage` API but that's not a good direction. A better approach would be using the device monitor tool from Android Studio where you can explore the device file system see: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer.html

Once you copy this to your desktop you can inspect the database using something like this: http://sqlitebrowser.org/

Personally I would just add a "hacker mode" to the app and integrate this  snippet from here so I can inspect the database: https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/db/Database.html

```
Style s = UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("TitleCommand");
FontImage icon = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_QUERY_BUILDER, s);
Form hi = new Form("SQL Explorer", new BorderLayout());
hi.getToolbar().addCommandToRightBar("", icon, (e) -> {
    TextArea query = new TextArea(3, 80);
    Command ok = new Command("Execute");
    Command cancel = new Command("Cancel");
    if(Dialog.show("Query", query, ok, cancel) == ok) {
        Database db = null;
        Cursor cur = null;
        try {
            db = Display.getInstance().openOrCreate("MyDB.db");
            if(query.getText().startsWith("select")) {
                cur = db.executeQuery(query.getText());
                int columns = cur.getColumnCount();
                hi.removeAll();
                if(columns > 0) {
                    boolean next = cur.next();
                    if(next) {
                        ArrayList<String[]> data = new ArrayList<>();
                        String[] columnNames = new String[columns];
                        for(int iter = 0 ; iter < columns ; iter++) {
                            columnNames[iter] = cur.getColumnName(iter);
                        }
                        while(next) {
                            Row currentRow = cur.getRow();
                            String[] currentRowArray = new String[columns];
                            for(int iter = 0 ; iter < columns ; iter++) {
                                currentRowArray[iter] = currentRow.getString(iter);
                            }
                            data.add(currentRowArray);
                            next = cur.next();
                        }
                        Object[][] arr = new Object[data.size()][];
                        data.toArray(arr);
                        hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, new Table(new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, arr)));
                    } else {
                        hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, "Query returned no results");
                    }
                } else {
                    hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, "Query returned no results");
                }
            } else {
                db.execute(query.getText());
                hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, "Query completed successfully");
            }
            hi.revalidate();
        } catch(IOException err) {
            Log.e(err);
            hi.removeAll();
            hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, "Error: " + err);
            hi.revalidate();
        } finally {
            Util.cleanup(db);
            Util.cleanup(cur);
        }
    }
});
hi.show();
```